# Extracting lines from multiline string with various variable length sections

Tags: python, arrays, string

I'm working with a pandas dataframe containing a large block of plain text for each row. The block of text has the following format:

```
Year 1
... (variable # of lines)
7. Stuff
... (variable # of lines, can be 0)
TOTAL Stuff
(single line, numeric)
... (variable # of lines)
Services 
(single line)
... (variable # of lines)
Year 2
... (same format as prev)
<repeats for n years>
TOTAL
... (same format as years)
Justification
... (variable number of lines)
<repeat m times>
```

I'm trying to extract the plain text under the "7. Stuff" and "Justification" headings as well a numerical values for "TOTAL Stuff". My current code creates a list based on the line breaks and iterates through them, but I feel like this is not efficient. It my current implementation also only works when there is one cycle of years -> Total -> Justification (not m).

Here is my `parse_text` function. Any help on making it more 'pythonic' or just efficient in general is greatly appreciated.

```
def parse_budget_text(row):
    stuff_value = 0
    stuff_text = ''
    justification_txt = ''
    #ensure text is not hidden within a list
    text = row['text_raw']
    #parse and sum equipment lines
    line_iter = iter([line.strip() for line in text.split("\n")])
    total_flag = False
    justification_flag = False
    for line in line_iter:
        #find each yearly section
        if line.startswith("YEAR"):
            while not line.startswith("7.  Stuff"):
                line = next(line_iter)
            line = next(line_iter)
            while not line.startswith("Services"):
                if ("TOTAL Stuff" not in line) and (not is_number(line))     and (line[0] != "$"):
                        stuff_txt += line+'; '
                line = next(line_iter)
        #find total summary
        elif line.startswith("TOTAL"):
            cumulative_flag = True
            while not line.startswith("TOTAL Stuff"):
                line =next(line_iter)
            stuff_value += int(next(line_iter).replace(',',''))
        #find Justification line
        elif line.startswith("Justification") and cumulative_flag:
            justification_flag = True
        #extract justification
        elif justification_flag == True:
            justification_txt += line                
    return pd.Series({'raw_text': text, 'Stuff_val': stuff_value, 'Stuff_txt': stuff_txt,})
```

Comment: Please describe the exact problem. If no problem, post that in code review section.

Comment: Look at your text, see if there is a pattern, construct a regular expression for that pattern, use the regex to extract the stuff you want.  If you work with text a lot it will be worth learning regular expressions - just don't assume it is a solution for everything.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re